# Which Bronze Saint bled the most?

Tags: saint-seiya

I remember a repeating joke when Saint Seiya was running that they bled too much. During their fights, which of the original main five Bronze Saints (Shiryu, Seya, Ikki, Shun, and Hyoga) had the highest count of bleeding episodes?

For objectivity, each episode where a saint was depicted bleeding counts as 1 point no matter how much or how many times they bled in a single episode.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Shiryu is the one who bled the most

[image]

While it's true that seiya fought and got injured so many times. Shiryu is the one who kept bleeding fight after fight almost thru all of his pores. He also gave half of his blood to repair the pegasus and his own cloth

Answer (score 1):

Without effectively counting the occurrences, I believe the easiest answer is Seiya himself as he is the real protagonist of the whole main series and the one that always fights more enemies than the others and defeats the final Boss/God of each series.